# Bootstraping for DataFrame in python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I am trying to resample my dataset using bootsrtaping technique without success, my code as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bootstrap as btstrap
#import scikits.bootstrap as sci
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as npr
sta_9147="//Users/talhadidi/Private/Desktop/9147.xlsx"
xlsx=pd.ExcelFile(sta_9147)
df1=pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')
df1.columns=df1.columns.astype(str)
x_resample = btstrap(['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd','DOOR_OPEN_SEC'], n=10000)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter("/ Users/talhadidi/Private/Desktop/testt5.xlsx")
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

the error i kept getting is :
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable,
could anyone help in, special thanks in advance.

Comment: What line does the error get called on?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\vtti.ad.vt.edu\Data\Users\talhadidi\Private\Desktop\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    x_resample = btstrap(['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd','DOOR_OPEN_SEC'], n=10000)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Well, you can't call the whole module, there's probably a function or method you need within the module